# How to hide css border-right using loop for even number in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am devolping app using angular js and ionic framework. I want to show border right only for odd numbers.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="media-body" style="padding-bottom:25px;">                           
                                    <h2 class="align_center">{{services.name}}</h2>

                                       <a href="#job/{{services.id}}">
                                        <h2 class="align_center_des">{{services.description}}</h2>


                                </div>
                            </div></div>
```

Here is the Css

```
.col-32-custom {
width: 32%;
float: left;
margin-left: 1%;
border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
margin-bottom: 31px;
height: 144px;
}
```

Here is fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/asetkL0n/

Comment: could you please prepare a jsfiddle for the issue..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/asetkL0n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS also allows you to target specific odd or even elements. An example to that could be:

```
.col-32-custom {
width: 32%;
float: left;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-bottom: 31px;
height: 144px;
}
.col-32-custom:nth-child(odd) {
border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
```

wherein, inside that nth-child, you can pass, "odd","even","2n","2n+1", or any expression in n.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use ng-class, so you have to create a class that will only add the border right.

I presume you are in an ng-repeat loop so the code will look like

```
<div data-ng-class="{border-right: ($index%2)===0}" class="col-32-custom">
```

Here you have the condition for the even number `($index%2)===0` so the div will have border-right class on event number.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-class-odd / ng-class-even within ng-repeat to add specific classes to this items.

example here : [ng-class-odd](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd)